# Laravel 5 how to add prefix to S3 file storage config?

Tags: laravel-5, amazon-s3, filesystems

In the **config/filesytems.php**, the default settings is like this

```
's3' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
    'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
],
```

Now, in development, there's only 1 bucket shared by all developers.

Is it possible to add a prefix *(as a subfolder)* to the config file?

For example

```
's3' => [
    ...
    'prefix' => 'jslim/',
],
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 21):

The configuration option you're looking for is called `root`:

```php
'disks' => [
    's3' => [
        'root' => 'jslim/',
        // 'root' => env('S3_PREFIX', env('APP_ENV') . '/'),
    ],
],
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I looked a long time before I found this and it worked perfectly. (I wish it was documented better.) You're a lifesaver!